# R repmat function for sparse matrices

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

for my r project, I need to repeat several big (i.e. bigger than 1000x1000) matrices. I found two versions the matlab repmat-function in r, that both work, but have severe limitations, so that I am unable to use them. Does anyone have another approach to solve this problem?

---

To decrease memory usage, I use the sparse-functions from the [Matrix-Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/Matrix.pdf) (`Diagonal()`, `Matrix(..., sparse=TRUE)`).

```
> m <- Diagonal(10000)
> object.size(m)
1168 bytes
```

Now, to repeat this matrix I use a r translation of the matlab function `repmat` (which can be found [here](https://haky-functions.blogspot.de/2006/11/repmat-function-matlab.html)):

```
repmat <- function(X, m, n){
    mx <- dim(X)[1]
    nx <- dim(X)[2]
    return(matrix(t(matrix(X,mx,nx*n)),mx*m,nx*n,byrow=T))
}
```

Unfortunately, this method uses the standard/dense version of a matrix and only works up to a certain object size, which is exceeded pretty fast within my project. Simply swapping the `matrix(...)` function with a `Matrix(..., sparse=TRUE)` one also wont work, because of the different parameter definitions for the matrix dimensions.

The only other solution would be the repmat-version from the [pcaMethods-Package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/repmat), where I am able to use the sparse matrices:

```
repmat <- function(mat, M, N) {
    ## Check if all input parameters are correct
    if( !all(M > 0, N > 0) ) {
        stop("M and N must be > 0")
    }    

    ## Convert array to matrix
    ma <- mat
    if(!is.matrix(mat)) {
        ma <- Matrix(mat, nrow=1, sparse=TRUE)
    }

    rows <- nrow(ma)
    cols <- ncol(ma)
    replicate <- Matrix(0, rows * M, cols * N, sparse=TRUE)

    for (i in 1:M) {
        for(j in 1:N) {
            start_row <- (i - 1) * rows + 1
            end_row <- i * rows
            start_col <- (j - 1) * cols + 1
            end_col <- j * cols
            replicate[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col] <- ma
        }
    }

     return(replicate)
}
```

However, this functions does the job, but needs a lot of runtime (probably because of the nested loops). My only option left is to increase the overall `memory.limit`, but this only results in running out of physical memory.

---

I am at my wits end here. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: What is slow is that you fill the sparse matrix one by one. Instead, compute all the indices of rows and columns that you need to fill, and create the entire sparse matrix in one go, in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Matrix methods for `rbind` and `cbind`:

```
repMat <- function(X, m, n){
  Y <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(X), m))
  do.call(cbind, rep(list(Y), n))
}


system.time(res <- repMat(m, 20, 30))
#user  system elapsed 
#0.48    0.44    0.92
str(res)
#Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
#  ..@ i       : int [1:6000000] 0 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000 60000 70000 80000 90000 ...
#  ..@ p       : int [1:300001] 0 20 40 60 80 100 120 140 160 180 ...
#  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 200000 300000
#  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  ..@ x       : num [1:6000000] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  ..@ factors : list()

object.size(res)
#73201504 bytes
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much.